# PHP Quickly identify if an object has selected properties = TRUE

Tags: php

Given a PHP object, for example:

```
[
    isAnimal->TRUE|FALSE,
    isMammal->TRUE|FALSE,
    hasFur->TRUE|FALSE,
    ...
]
```

Does anyone know a nicer, one line way of starting with and array of filters like such:

```
$filters = array('isAnimal, hasFur');
```

and returning *TRUE* if the object matches both filters than writing a function that would loop through every filter individually and check if the object matches?

Comment: If you write a suitable function, it will then be a one-liner.

Comment: Already wrote it, was just curious if there was a sexy php trick that would look nicer, by merging arrays or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I didn't miss something and this helps:

```
$filter = array('hasEyes'=>true,'hasHead'=>true);
if (!array_diff_assoc($filter,(array)$obj))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks friend :) I didn't plan on setting TRUE/FALSE values on my filter array but I guess I could make it work that way for more flexibility like requesting a FALSE value!

Comment: Essentially the filter having values  enables array_diff_assoc to check the keys/values against the object in the first place. And yeah, it also adds the option to check against FALSE values. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) over the array of filters to test the individual properties of the object, reducing them to a single boolean value. Something like

```
class myObject {
    public $name;
    public $isAnimal;
    public $isMammal;
    public $hasFur;

    public function __construct($name, $isAnimal = false, $isMammal = false, $hasFur = false) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->isAnimal = $isAnimal;
        $this->isMammal = $isMammal;
        $this->hasFur = $hasFur;
    }
}

$table = new myObject('Table');
$dolphin = new myObject('Dolphin', true, true);
$dog = new myObject('Dog', true, true, true);

$objectSet = [
    $table,
    $dolphin,
    $dog,
];

$filters = array('isAnimal', 'hasFur');

foreach($objectSet as $objectValue) {
    var_dump(
        $objectValue->name,
        array_reduce(
            $filters, 
            function($returnValue, $filter) use ($objectValue) {
                $returnValue &= $objectValue->{$filter};
                return (bool) $returnValue;
            },
            true
        )
    );
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LJ5QB)

Comment: The array_reduce() line is a bit too long for me, but that's a good approach still, thanks!